# Is there a way of using the entire memory of my GPU for CUML calculations?

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rapids

I am new to the RAPIDS AI world and I decided to try CUML and CUDF out for the first time.
I am running UBUNTU 18.04 on WSL 2. My main OS is Windows 11. I have a 64 GB RAM and a laptop RTX 3060 6 GB GPU.

At the time I am writing this post, I am running a TSNE fitting calculation over a CUDF dataframe composed by approximately 26 thousand values, stored in 7 columns (all the values are numerical or binary ones, since the categorical ones have been one hot encoded).
While classifiers like LogisticRegression or SVM were really fast, TSNE seems taking a while to output results (it's been more than a hour now, and it is still going on even if the Dataframe is not so big). The task manager is telling me that 100% of GPU is being used for the calculations even if, by running "nvidia-smi" on the windows powershell, the command returns that only 1.94 GB out of a total of 6 GB are currently in use. This seems odd to me since I read papers on RAPIDS AI's TSNE algorithm being 20x faster than the standard scikit-learn one.

I wonder if there is a way of increasing the percentage of dedicated GPU memory to perform faster computations or if it is just an issue related to WSL 2 (probably it limits the GPU usage at just 2 GB).

Any suggestion or thoughts?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The task manager is telling me that 100% of GPU is being used for the calculations

I'm not sure if the Windows Task Manager will be able to tell you of GPU throughput that is being achieved for computations.

> "nvidia-smi" on the windows powershell, the command returns that only 1.94 GB out of a total of 6 GB are currently in use

Memory utilisation is a different calculation than GPU throughput. Any GPU application will only use as much memory as is requested, and there is no correlation between higher memory usage and higher throughput, unless the application specifically mentions a way that it can achieve higher throughput by using more memory (for example, a different algorithm for the same computation may use more memory).

> TSNE seems taking a while to output results (it's been more than a hour now, and it is still going on even if the Dataframe is not so big).

This definitely seems odd, and not the expected behavior for a small dataset. What version of cuML are you using, and what is your `method` argument for the fit task? Could you also open an issue at [www.github.com/rapidsai/cuml/issues](http://www.github.com/rapidsai/cuml/issues) with a way to access your dataset so the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the clarification you provided about the GPU memory usage, I was not aware of this.
Regarding CUML and the TSNE algorithm: I am using the RAPIDS AI stable 21.12 release, installed via Conda (Python v. 3.8; CUDA v. 11.5).
Regarding the TSNE method argument, I left everything as default: I just wrote 'n_components = 2', which is a default setting.